# Create 4D upper diagonal array from 3D

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say that I have a `(x, y, z)` sized matrix. Now, I wish to create a new matrix of dimension `(x, y, i, i)`, where the `(i, i)` matrix is upper diagonal and constructed from the values on the `z`-dimension. Is there some easy way of doing this in `numpy` without using more than 1 for-loop (looping over x)? Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
original = np.array([
    [
        [0, 1, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ],
    [
        [7, 8, 9],
        [3, 2, 1]
    ],
])

new = np.array([
    [
        [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 3]
        ],
        [
            [4, 5],
            [0, 6]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [7, 8],
            [0, 9]
        ],
        [
            [3, 2],
            [0, 1]
        ]
    ]
])
```

So, using the above we see that

```
original[0, 0, :] = [0 1 3]

new[0, 0, :, :] = [[0 1]
                  [0 3]]
```

Comment: Could you show how `output[0,0,:,:]` would look like given `input[0,0,:]`? Maybe use a sample case for that.

Comment: @Divakar I've added an example - does it make sense?

Comment: To be honest, nothing really. I know how to do it by looping over the `x` and `y`-dimensions. However, this will be way too slow.

Comment: Thank you, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `boolean-indexing` -

```
n = 2 # This would depend on a.shape[-1]
out = np.zeros(a.shape[:2] + (n,n,),dtype=a.dtype)
out[:,:,np.arange(n)[:,None] <= np.arange(n)] = a
```

Sample run -

```
In [247]: a
Out[247]: 
array([[[0, 1, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[7, 8, 9],
        [3, 2, 1]]])

In [248]: out
Out[248]: 
array([[[[0, 1],
         [0, 3]],

        [[4, 5],
         [0, 6]]],


       [[[7, 8],
         [0, 9]],

        [[3, 2],
         [0, 1]]]])
```

Another approach could be suggested using `subscripted-indexing` to replace the last step -

```
r,c = np.triu_indices(n)
out[:,:,r,c] = a
```

**Note :** As stated earlier, `n` would depend on `a.shape[-1]`. Here, we had `a.shape[-1]` as `3`, so `n` was `2`. If `a.shape[-1]` were `6`, `n` would be `3` and so on. The relationship is : `(n*(n+1))//2 == a.shape[-1]`.

Comment: Many thanks Divakar! This worked flawlessly. Yes, I find `n` by simply backing it out of sum of the first integers. I must add that this solution is so elegant it hurts my eyes